# Bad STL Headers

Tags: c++, stl, header, set

I want to make some STL sets but when I do it tells me

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

Meaning I have not included the proper header define (`#define <set>`) but I have.  Are sets just under a different location?  The source looks like this

```
set<int> playerlist;
```

The header files are...

```
#include <iostream>

//#include "winsock2.h"
#include "Ws2tcpip.h"
#include <list>

//#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

#include <set>
```

Comment: Did you do `using namespace std;`? You need to specify it's from the namespace. `std::set<int>`works too.

Comment: ¤ Make sure you `#include <set>`. Note that the preprocessor directive is **`#include`**, not `#define`. Then either write qualified `std::set` instead of plain `set`, or have a `using namespace std` or `using std::set` directive. Cheers & hth,

Comment: I am using std and I tried std::set<int> mylist

Comment: Can you tell us all of the STL header's you're including your project and in what order?

Comment: Yep, the directive is #include

Answer (score 2):

What you need is

```
#include <set>
```

and not

```
#define <set>
```

also before using the set write the following line before your main function

```
using namespace std;
```

Answer (score 0):

By

```
#define <set>
```

I hope you mean

```
#include <set>
```

?

You also need to indicate somehow that you want the `set` from the `std` namespace. You can do that either by prefixing `set` with `std::` everywhere that you refer to it:

```
set<int> playerlist;
```

or by using a `using` declaration to tell the compiler that whenever you refer to `set`, you mean `std::set`:

```
using std::set;
```

(It's also possible to write a catch-all `using namespace std;` declaration that says that you always want to use everything from the `std` namespace, but that's normally considered bad practice. I mention it only because, despite being bad practice, it's fairly common, so you may well come across code that does it.)